# Twig - Mimic PHP for loop functionality in twig with iterations of +5 (or anything other than +1)

Tags: php, for-loop, symfony, twig

How can I mimic this PHP functionality in twig? I need to increment a number by 5 for each iteration of a for loop. The PHP code below works as expected:

```
for($x=5; $x<=20; $x+=5)
{
    echo $x,'<br>';  
}
```

which outputs:

```
5 ,10 ,15 ,20 ,
```

However this code in twig does not work as expected.

```
{% for y in range(0, 20) %}
{{ y + 5 }}&nbsp;,
{% endfor %}
```

Which outputs:

```
5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 , 15 , 16 , 17 , 18 , 19 , 20 , 21 , 22 , 23 , 24 , 25
```

I have also tried setting the new value of y for each iteration however that does not work either...

```
{% for y in range(0, 20) %}
{{ y + 5 }}&nbsp;,
{% set y = y + 5 %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
{% for y in range(5, 20, 5) %}
{{ y }}&nbsp;,
{% endfor %}
```